# Building text-similarity time series in a corpus of tweets

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I want to measure the evolution of text similarity over time. My data frame consists on a column for tweet identifiers ( `id`) a column for dates with a daily frequency (`date`) and a column with the tidy text of the tweets (`clean_text`).

Here is a brief `repex` with some actual cleaned tweets:

```
final <- data.frame(id=1:5,Date=c(as.Date("2020-12-26"),as.Date("2020-12-26"),as.Date("2020-12-27"),
                    as.Date("2020-12-27"),as.Date("2020-12-27")),
              clean_text = c("americans died covid nfebruary people couple days",
                                        "cops crush peoples necks death eric garner",  
                                        "video clip tells george floyd resist arrest earlier claimed police officer", 
                                        "black americans terrible daily dangers outdoor spaces subjected unwarranted suspicion", 
                                         "announcement waiting minneapolis police officer derek chauvin charged manslaug"))
```

Since I want something that permits me to measure how similar/disimilar text became with time, I thought about using some similarity measures (i.e frequency, cosine similarity...), via `textstat_simil` from `quanteda`.

Here is my try:

```
require(quanteda)            
start <- as.Date("2020-12-26",format="%Y-%m-%d")
    end   <- as.Date("2020-12-27",format="%Y-%m-%d")
    
    theDate <- start
    i=1
    
    similarity<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = as.numeric(end+1-start), ncol = 1))
    #value<-vector(mode="numeric")
    colnames(similarity)<-c("value")
    while (theDate <= end){
      if (nrow(subset(final,final$Date==theDate))>1){
        corp <- corpus(subset(final,final$Date==theDate),
                       docid_field = "id",
                       text_field = "clean_text")
        a<-as.matrix(dfm(corp) %>%
                       textstat_simil())
        
            similarity$value[i]<-sum(a[lower.tri(a)])/length(corp)
      }else{
        similarity$value[i]<-0
      } 
      i<-i+1
      theDate <- theDate + 1 
      
    }
```

In this code, I am summing over the lower triangular elements of the correlation matrix `a` and dividing by the number of tweets to get a "mean" of the correlation over the tweets. I believe this is the problematic step, since, when I apply this function to my corpus of tweets the similarity drops precisely in the moments where tweets are very related.

Also I must say that my goal is to obtain a time series with a column for a measure of similarity and another for dates so it can be plotted. Maybe there is a simpler npl method to track this?

edit: Just realised that the correlation entries in matrix `a` are negative. Not sure how to interpret that or whether there is an error in the coding then?

Comment: Can you clarify what your benchmark is? For each day, you want the similarity of all tweets from that day to all tweets from the previous day? Or the similarity of all tweets to each other within the day? For the first, you could aggregate the day's tweets into one "document". For the second, you would need to summarise the total similarity pairs, for instance through a mean. Please clarify your desired answer.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. It is the second you mentioned. I want the  similarity of all the tweets within a day. My idea is that applying that to the whole period would give me a time series of similarity scores that somehow determines if tweet's text has become more cohesive over time. Do you believe my code is in the right direction for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.1
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
library("quanteda.textstats")

dfmat <- final %>%
  corpus(text_field = "clean_text") %>%
  tokens() %>%
  dfm()
```

Now we will create a series of dfm objects, by date:

```r
date_splits <- split(seq_len(ndoc(dfmat)), dfmat$Date)
date_splits
## $`2020-12-26`
## [1] 1 2
## 
## $`2020-12-27`
## [1] 3 4 5

dfmat_split <- lapply(date_splits, function(x) dfmat[x, ])
dfmat_split
## $`2020-12-26`
## Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 41 features (82.93% sparse) and 2 docvars.
##        features
## docs    americans died covid nfebruary people couple days cops crush peoples
##   text1         1    1     1         1      1      1    1    0     0       0
##   text2         0    0     0         0      0      0    0    1     1       1
## [ reached max_nfeat ... 31 more features ]
## 
## $`2020-12-27`
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 41 features (75.61% sparse) and 2 docvars.
##        features
## docs    americans died covid nfebruary people couple days cops crush peoples
##   text3         0    0     0         0      0      0    0    0     0       0
##   text4         1    0     0         0      0      0    0    0     0       0
##   text5         0    0     0         0      0      0    0    0     0       0
## [ reached max_nfeat ... 31 more features ]
```

Then, create a list of data.frame results, by date, by coercing each `textstat_simil()` matrix output into a data.frame, and then join these up in an output data.frame where we add back the date columns.  This gives us a data.frame of (unique) pairwise similarities, by date:

```r
simil_by_date <- lapply(dfmat_split, function(x) {
  textstat_simil(x) %>%
    as.data.frame()
})
simil_by_date
## $`2020-12-26`
##   document1 document2 correlation
## 1     text1     text2  -0.2058824
## 
## $`2020-12-27`
##   document1 document2 correlation
## 1     text3     text4 -0.34391797
## 2     text3     text5 -0.05514368
## 3     text4     text5 -0.30120725

df <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(rep(names(simil_by_date), sapply(simil_by_date, nrow))),
  do.call(rbind, simil_by_date),
  row.names = NULL
)
df
##         date document1 document2 correlation
## 1 2020-12-26     text1     text2 -0.20588235
## 2 2020-12-27     text3     text4 -0.34391797
## 3 2020-12-27     text3     text5 -0.05514368
## 4 2020-12-27     text4     text5 -0.30120725
```

Now it's simple to aggregate the similarities using your function of choice.  Here, I've used **dplyr** to do this by mean correlation:

```r
library("dplyr")
## 
## Attaching package: 'dplyr'
## The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
## 
##     filter, lag
## The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
## 
##     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(simil = mean(correlation))
## # A tibble: 2 x 2
##   date        simil
##   <date>      <dbl>
## 1 2020-12-26 -0.206
## 2 2020-12-27 -0.233
```